# pgfplots: plot subset of data from a table using indexing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I have a simple .txt file with 2 columns (x and y coordinates). With pgfplots, it's easy to plot x against y (i.e., all the elements of the 1st column against all the elements of the 2nd column), but how to plot a subset of x against a subset of y using indexing?

This is an example of what I would like to do, written in **Matlab** code:

```
x=(1:1:10).';
y=x.^2;

T=table(x,y);
writetable(T,'data.txt');

figure
hold on;
plot(x,y,'k');                       % <-- easy
plot(x(1:3:10),y(1:3:10),'r');       % <-- how to do this?
plot([x(1) x(10)],[y(1) y(10)],'b'); % <-- how to do this?
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
```

The figure generated by the above Matlab code is the following:

[image]

The data.txt file generated by the above Matlab code contains the following:

```
x,y
1,1
2,4
3,9
4,16
5,25
6,36
7,49
8,64
9,81
10,100
```

Minimum working example with **pgfplots**:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    width=5cm,
    height=5cm,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    grid=both,
]

\addplot[line width=1pt, black]
table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] 
{data.txt};
    
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Could you show what the Matlab code would output? I am not familiar with this software. Also, does the output txt file contain these backslashes at the end of each line? You may want to look up "filters" in the [PGFplots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).

Comment: I updated the question by fixing the output txt file and including the Matlab figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `filter`s:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
x,y 
1,1 
2,4 
3,9 
4,16
5,25 
6,36 
7,49 
8,64 
9,81 
10,100
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    %width=5cm,
    %height=5cm,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    grid=both,
]

\addplot[line width=1pt, black] table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.txt};

\addplot[line width=1pt, red, 
    x filter/.expression={(mod(x - 1, 3) == 0 ? \pgfmathresult : NaN)}
] table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.txt};

\addplot[line width=1pt, blue, 
    x filter/.expression={(x == 1 || x == 10 ? \pgfmathresult : NaN)}
] table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.txt};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to keep the colon notation from Matlab, you could create your custom style:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
x,y 
1,1 
2,4 
3,9 
4,16
5,25 
6,36 
7,49 
8,64 
9,81 
10,100
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
    colon notation/.style args={#1(#2:#3:#4)}{
        /pgfplots/#1 filter/.expression={(mod(#1 - #2, #3) == 0 && #1 <= #4 ? \pgfmathresult : NaN)}
    }
}

\begin{axis}[
    %width=5cm,
    %height=5cm,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    grid=both,
]

\addplot[line width=1pt, black] table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.txt};

\addplot[line width=1pt, red, colon notation={x(1:3:10)}] table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.txt};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you need to filter elements depending on their index rather than on their value, you can use `\coordindex` which start with 0:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
x,y 
1,1 
2,4 
3,9 
4,16
5,25 
6,36 
7,49 
8,64 
9,81 
10,100
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    %width=5cm,
    %height=5cm,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    grid=both,
]

\addplot[line width=1pt, black] table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.txt};

\addplot[line width=1pt, red, 
    x filter/.expression={(mod(\coordindex, 3) == 0 ? \pgfmathresult : NaN)}
] table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.txt};

\addplot[line width=1pt, blue, 
    x filter/.expression={(\coordindex == 0 || \coordindex == 9 ? \pgfmathresult : NaN)}
] table [x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.txt};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to clarify, the Matlab notation "x(start:step:end)" means "all the elements of the array x from x(start) to x(end) equispaced by step. Is that what your "colon notation" does here? I'm trying to learn to handle elements of an array (i.e., column of a table) by specifying the index and not the value.

Comment: Here, it's just a coincidence that each element of x is equal to the corresponding index. If it's confusing, I'll change that in the example.

Comment: @TheDon Well, `colon notation` does `x(start:step:end)`, but on the value of *x*, not on it's index. It might be not quite the same then ... Maybe not even the right thing to use. But the filters should work anyways.

Comment: I seems to me that also the filter is picking the elements based on the value of x (e.g., "x == 1 || x == 10"), or am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps a simpler question would be: how do you select an element of an array (i.e., an element of a column in a table) in pgfplots? In Matlab, this would be simply x(i) to pick the i-th element.

Comment: @TheDon Yes, it does indeed. If you need it to pick elements based in the index, you would need to use `\coordindex`, which starts from 0 though.

Comment: @TheDon PGF has `array(x,y)`, so `\pgfmathparse{array({9,13,17,21},2)} \pgfmathresult` would return `17`. You can also do `\def\myarray{{9,13,17,21}} \pgfmathparse{\myarray[2]} \pgfmathresult`. But you need to have properly formatted arrays and you need to be inside a PGF context.

Comment: For what I understand, \coordindex yields the current index of the table row (starting with 0). Can you pick such an index to plot specific elements of an array?

Comment: @TheDon Maybe you should ask a new question and make clear what you want to achieve. I edited my answer so that it also accounts for `\coordindex`.

Comment: @TheDon I would have to rephrase everything. So I'd rather keep it this way. The answer is there anyways.